# Errors in R console

Tags: macos, error, r

I've recently upgraded to a new MBP (2015 series) and migrated my old machine via a time machine backup. Since the upgrade, I have been receiving error messages in the console of `R` at more or less random intervals. The warnings usually appear when I start the `R.app`, occasionally when I switch from another app (like `TextMate`) back to R.app, and then even more occasionally just on random.

The messages typically look like this:

> 2016-12-12 10:35:18.696 R[2635:12228] IMKInputSession presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:completionHandler: : *NO* NSRemoteViewController to client, NSError=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection from pid 0 was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection from pid 0 was invalidated from this process.}, com.apple.inputmethod.EmojiFunctionRowItem

or this:

> 2016-12-06 15:05:02.067 R[87426:4480089] IMKClient Stall detected, please Report your user scenario attaching a spindump (or sysdiagnose) that captures the problem - (imkxpc_presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:reply:) block performed very slowly (59.22 secs).

I had already posted [a question on Stackoverflow about the latter problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997541/r-warnings-imkclient-stall-detected), but have not received any replies. I was hoping that you guys at Ask Different might have an idea of where this error comes from, and how I might be able to fix it.

Comment: When you upgraded did you chnage version of macOS? and how was R.app installed

Comment: My old machine was on the most recent version of Sierra and I updated the new MBP before migrating data via the Time Machine backup. R was migrated via Time Machine. I reinstalled since then, using the Mac Installer from CRAN. I was hoping that would fix the issue but it did not.

Comment: I also get the same problem on Sierra. Whenever I run code in the terminal in R, open a Quartz window to visualize a plot, then click on the plot, I get the following message in the terminal: IMKInputSession presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:completionHandler: : *NO* NSRemoteViewController to client, NSError=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection from pid 0 was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection from pid 0 was invalidated from this process.}, com.apple.inputmethod.EmojiFunctionRowItem So annoying ... R version 3.3.2 (201